# How to make box2d mouse joint works similar to box2d setposition

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone, jbox2d

I want to make b2mouse joint working similar to b2setposition, though i know in mouse joint force is applied, so it's not possible to reach the desired point without any delay like setPosition(), but i want to make it works as close as b2setPosition(). So on which mousejoint/body  properties should i work on so that it acts as close as b2setposition.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Making the maximum force of the mouse joint very strong is about all you can do.

Comment: i used max force:10000 friction:0 , Damping ratio:0.1. So any way to do better??

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Box2D API Reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/classb2_mouse_joint.html) on b2MouseJoint:

> NOTE: this joint is not documented in the manual because it was
>   developed to be used in the testbed. If you want to learn how to use
>   the mouse joint, look at the testbed.

There's no "b2setposition". There's b2Position which is an internal class, or you meant b2Body->SetTransform() which sets the position of a body.

If you could explain better what you're trying to do and why it has to be a b2Mouse joint, I might be able to help more.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, whatever the name of the method, this function directly set the position of any body. So i want to achieve this things using mouse joint, though i know it's not possible to make it same using mouse joint,i want to make it as close as possible.